# Receiving Non -HTTP resposne code exception when running JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

When running a test with JMeter/Blazemeter I am receiving the below errors after a certain period randomly from 10-20 minutes after the test begins.

- Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
- 500 Internal server error
- Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.TruncatedChunkException
- Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException

I have Apache and Weblogic servers. I have attempted the below

- Changing the Client Implementation to HTTPClient4
- Updating the user.properties file and hc.parameters file with below respectively

  ```
    httpclient4.retrycount=1
    hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters

    http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
  ```
- Disabling 'Use Keep-Alive'  in the HTTP Requests.

Is there a solution for the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think this is JMeter-related problem? [HTTP status codes 5xx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#server_error_responses) are **server side errors** so I would recommend instead of tweaking JMeter look into the system under test, in particular:

1. Load Balancer/reverse proxy or what is [Apache used for logs](https://blog.codeasite.com/how-do-i-find-apache-http-server-log-files/)
2. [Weblogic logs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/logging/viewing.html)
3. Whether all backend components have enough resources in terms of CPU, RAM, network, disk, etc, if you don't have an APM tool in place you can consider using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
4. Configuration of the Apache/Weblogic/Database/other middleware as all of them need to be properly tuned for the high loads.

- [HttpHostConnectException](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/HttpHostConnectException.html)  - means that connection cannot be established
- [TruncatedChunkException](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-5.1.x/current/httpcore5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/core5/http/TruncatedChunkException.html)  - means that you received incomplete response
- [NoHttpResponseException](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/NoHttpResponseException.html) - means that response could not be parsed as HTTP packed

So my expectation is that your application gets **overloaded** hence cannot properly respond to JMeter requests. I don't also think that you're getting errors "randomly", try starting with 1 thread and gradually increasing the load until you start getting the errors, this way you will be able to state which amount of users/requests per second is "safe", what is the maximum, when response time starts growing, when errors start occurring, whether application gets back to normal when the load decreases, etc.

Comment: I had assumed this is due to load , but the initially I tested with 850 users then reduced to 280 users and then with 10 users .In all the cases , the errors appeared . Sometimes the errors appeared in the first 5-10 minutes . Sometimes after 20 minutes. I have had previously run the test successfully with 850 users multiple times..